# how to best capture the value in an sl-input component from the shoelace library

Tags: javascript, web-component, shoelace

I am reasonably new to the shoelace web component library. I am trying to implement a callback to validate an input.

The only way I have found to capture the value in the input is to use `evt.path[0].value` when handling the `slInput` event. Is that really the way to do it. I see no example for this on https://shoelace.style

below is a jsx example. Assume that the `validate()` function does some magic to the current input value.

```
render() {
    return <sl-input 
               type="text"
               onSlInput={(evt) => doSomethingWithValue(evt.path[0].value)}
           />
}
```

The above is working but a) `.path` is not a standard property of `CustomEvent` and b) what guarantee do I have that the value is always in `path[0]`?

**edit:**
this works.

```
render() {
    return <sl-input 
               type="text"
               onSlInput={(evt) => doSomethingWithValue(evt.target.value)}
           />
}
```

Comment: I am now confused as to how the above ever worked! But I have found the answer. `evt.target.value` does the trick

Comment: `CustomEvent.path` is a Chrome only property. testing on both browsers caused my confusion.